# can't open fuse device in a docker container when mounting a davfs2 volume

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile, mount, fuse

I encounter the following error when I try to mount a davfs2 volume on a docker container :

```
geoserver@8e8091d97157:~$ mount owncloud/
/sbin/mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse
/sbin/mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse failed
/sbin/mount.davfs: waiting for /dev/fuse to be created
/sbin/mount.davfs: can't open fuse device
/sbin/mount.davfs: trying coda kernel file system
/sbin/mount.davfs: no free coda device to mount
```

The Dockerfile has the following content :

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM linux

# environment variables
ENV GEOSERVER_PASS  geoserver

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y davfs2 fuse

RUN groupadd --gid 999 geoserver
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --home /home/geoserver \
        -p $(echo "print crypt("${GEOSERVER_PASS:-geoserver}", "salt")" | perl) \
        --uid 999 --gid 999 geoserver

USER geoserver
RUN mkdir /home/geoserver/owncloud
RUN mkdir /home/geoserver/.davfs2

USER root
ADD secrets /home/geoserver/.davfs2/secrets
RUN chown geoserver:geoserver /home/geoserver/.davfs2/secrets
RUN chmod 0600 /home/geoserver/.davfs2/secrets

RUN chmod u+s /sbin/mount.davfs
RUN perl -p -i -e "s/#\s*use_locks\s*1/use_locks 0/" /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf
RUN adduser geoserver davfs2
RUN echo "https://my-owncloud-server.org/owncloud/remote.php/webdav /home/geoserver/owncloud davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

The device /dev/fuse exists

```
root@8e8091d97157:/# ls -l /dev/fuse
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 229 Oct 18 12:06 /dev/fuse
```

But the mount fails...
i do not see interesting things in the logs :

/var/log/daemon.log

```
root@8e8091d97157:/# tail /var/log/daemon.log 
Oct 18 12:36:03 8e8091d97157 mount.davfs: davfs2 1.5.2
Oct 18 12:36:04 8e8091d97157 mount.davfs: the server certificate is not trusted
Oct 18 12:36:04 8e8091d97157 mount.davfs:   issuer: TERENA, Amsterdam, Noord-Holland, NL
Oct 18 12:36:04 8e8091d97157 mount.davfs:   subject: Domain Control Validated
Oct 18 12:36:04 8e8091d97157 mount.davfs:   identity: owncloud-mshe.univ-fcomte.fr
Oct 18 12:36:04 8e8091d97157 mount.davfs:   accepted by user
```

/var/log/debug

```
root@8e8091d97157:/# tail /var/log/debug 
Oct 18 12:36:03 8e8091d97157 mount.davfs: davfs2 1.5.2
```

/var/log/auth.log

```
root@8e8091d97157:/# tail /var/log/auth.log 
Oct 18 12:35:59 8e8091d97157 su[890]: Successful su for geoserver by root
Oct 18 12:35:59 8e8091d97157 su[890]: + ??? root:geoserver
Oct 18 12:35:59 8e8091d97157 su[890]: pam_env(su:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Oct 18 12:35:59 8e8091d97157 su[890]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user geoserver by (uid=0)
Oct 18 12:36:09 8e8091d97157 su[890]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user geoserver
```

So everything seems to be normal.
I would be happy to get some help.
Thanks.

Ernest.

Answer (score 2):

Thank's, successfully mounted by adding

```
--privileged --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse
```

in to docker run command.

Answer (score 1):

Those security options are too open. FUSE support is now documented at 
[Docker runtime privileges](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities). All you need are -cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Indeed, as explained [in the DockerCVMFS documentation](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Main/DockerCVMFS), "*it is possible to run FUSE filesystems inside a container, but FUSE must be enabled on the host system. Docker will not enable you to load kernel modules that you couldn't load on the host*".

Consequently, i tried to load the module fuse in the host, as explained in [modprobe in a docker container](http://dummdida.tumblr.com/post/117157045170/modprobe-in-a-docker-container)

I used the following command to launch the container, and the mount is ok now :

```
docker run --name geosync_ssh_data_1 --privileged --cap-add=ALL -v /dev:/dev -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules geosync_ssh_data
```

The solution includes tree steps :

```
Run the container in privileged mode (--privileged)
Add all capabilities (--cap-add=ALL)
Passthrough /lib/modules into the container (-v /lib/modules:/lib/modules)
```

hope it helps.

one question remains : is the only way to do that ?

Ernest.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get it working using docker-compose with these additional settings. Could someone advise please? Once fixed I'll change this answer to reflect the correct method using docker-compose.

It works perfectly without the cap_add, /dev/fuse device, or /lib/modules volume when it is run after the container is loaded - it just fails to mount when run from the dockerfile (with the exact same error as the OP posted). Wondering if there's a syntax issue in the docker-compose.yml file, here it is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: mycontainer
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN 
    devices:
      - /dev/fuse
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/log
      - ./:/var/www/html/public
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules
    env_file:
      - .env
```