# Mount WebDAV inside rented docker container instance

Tags: docker, mount, webdav, fuse

I'm trying to mount directory over network inside of a rented docker container instance. But this seems to need access to a /dev/fuse device OR a coda device according to the error messages...

I run the following public Docker container: **nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-base-ubuntu20.04**

I installed davfs2 via apt-get and tried to run the following commands to mount my WebDAV supplied via an external OwnCloud server (Note: username and domain were changed to user123 and example.org):

```
mkdir /root/dav
mount -t davfs https://example.org/files/remote.php/dav/files/user123/ /root/dav
Please enter the username to authenticate with server
https://example.org/files/remote.php/dav/files/user123/ or hit enter for none.
  Username: user123
Please enter the password to authenticate user user123 with server
https://example.org/files/remote.php/dav/files/user123/ or hit enter for none.
  Password:  
/sbin/mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse
/sbin/mount.davfs: loading kernel module fuse failed
/sbin/mount.davfs: waiting for /dev/fuse to be created
/sbin/mount.davfs: can't open fuse device
/sbin/mount.davfs: trying coda kernel file system
/sbin/mount.davfs: no free coda device to mount
```

My research on this issue ends in solutions where the docker container MUST run with special permissions, which I have no access to. (I'm using vast.ai just in case this matters):
[can't open fuse device in a docker container when mounting a davfs2 volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106108/cant-open-fuse-device-in-a-docker-container-when-mounting-a-davfs2-volume) --> Solution here is to add `--privileged --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse` to the docker startup options **which vast.ai doesn't allow me to do** (for a good reason I believe, since this would probably allow to break out of the container easily).

Also mounting a sshfs mountpoint inside the container seems to require a fuse device.

Is there any other option to have realtime access to a network drive at a mount point? I don't want to use rsync as this uses lots of network traffic to sync files that are not needed and also slows down the container startup...

### EDIT

I found the following thread at the Docker GitHub, which is all about FUSE device support. Seems as of today it's not easily possible activate FUSE support for docker containers without modifications to the host OS configuration or running the docker container with elevated permissions...
It's an issue that seems to be unsolved since 2018, which is now about 5 years ago...

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/321